# Find a matrix that forces a vector into a lower dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I'm stuck in this one problem in Linear Algebra. it says:

Let $A_i$ be the matrix that projects $x\in\Bbb R^n$ onto the $n−1$ dimensional space so that $x_i=  0$. What is the form of $A_i$? What happens when you consider the following iteration:  Let $b_1=(A_1)x$.  For $i= 2,3, . . . ,n : b_i= (A_i)b_{i−1}$.  What is $b_n$?

I've been working on this for a couple of days now, but I still don't understand how to start this problem.

Comment: You need to put a $ sign before and after each MathJax expression to make the MathJax work

Comment: Look at $\mathbb{R}^3$ as an example. $A_1$ would map vectors $(x,y,z)$ onto $(y,z)$ and $(x,0,0)$ onto $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at $\Bbb R^3$ for example. The matrix $A_2$ should satisfy
$$
A_2 \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3} = \pmatrix{x_1\\0\\x_3}.
$$
In other words,
$$
A_2 \pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3} = \pmatrix{
1 x_1 + 0x_2 + 0x_3\\
0 x_1 + 0x_2 + 0x_3\\
0 x_1 + 0x_2 + 1x_3}.
$$
With that established, what is the matrix of $A_2$? What should $A_i$ be in the general case?